# React router onEnter option vs Component life cycle Method to check for authorized users

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

Which is better?

I tried `onEnter` but that lead to flickering between paths. The `onEnter` check ran before the component was loaded. It routed and then re-routed after user was authenticated which was visually unpleasing.  Now I'm just using `Main` component's `componentWillMount` lifecycle to run the authorization code and re-route if is resolved else stay there. If I use only lifecycle method to check then I can't use `Link` component  from react-router. Any thoughts on how to solve the flickering or improve the client side security without crappy ui.

Comment: Could you post a code sample?

Comment: in my case if I use onEnter none of the lifecycle methods get called.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should do it in the componentDidMount and not on the componentWillMount since it can freeze the entire application if the process takes some time.

As for your problem, you can do the check in tje componentDidMount and then use react router's browserHistory to manually push the url.

Take a look at the histories docs of react router:
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but i seems i should use react-router on-Enter for <Link> tags since that does not rerender the main component.

Comment: <Link> just pushes the url to the browserHistory, its the same, but you cant use link on lifecycle event since its a component so just do it manually